# React: Support for integrating multiple OAuth2 authorization servers (SSO) using generic npm package

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I'm using **React** for my front end and Spring boot for Backend. The idea is to enable the OAuth2 authentication and generate access token by calling authorization server.

Say the customer can use any authorization server of their choice. So the code should use a generic protocol/dependency to support any auth server.

So I have to implement the Oauth2 authentication with openid connect(to handle roles) with **generic npm package** to support all Oauth2 authorization servers (KeyCloak, AWS Cognitio, Okta...). I don't want to use any specific package for each OAuth server (Say for KeyCloak there is a separate package keycloak-js, I don't need that).

**Note:**
Customer will use one auth server at a time (Say Aws cognito). I Just started testing with KeyCloak. But the React code **npm package** and **configurations**

> ```
> client id,
> client secret,
> client app,
> grant type
> ```

should commonly support any authorization server. In my application there is no social login just using the user management and access control from the OAuth server.

If any one worked on this with **same npm package** to support all authorization servers kindly let me know or give some ideas for how to do this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I found the oidc-client npm package for this purpose. But still checking on the proper code examples with react. Most of the code samples are in Typescript.